# Cassandra Production ready on Windows?

Tags: c#, sql, database, nosql, cassandra

Question anyone know of any success stories of Cassandra running on windows in  a production environment?  I'm doing some work on Cassandra and trying to find the correct platform for it currently the platform is windows running MS-SQLas the data store. what are the dis-advantages if any when running Cassandra  on a windows environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any actual production deployments in Windows, no.  (I only know of one non-Linux deployment, on FreeBSD.)  Should it work fine?  Yes.  Is there a relative paucity of tools (e.g. count the .bat files vs shell scripts in bin/)?  Yes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any sites.  I do not believe offically supporting Windows is a priority for the Cassandra dev team either, based on some comments I've seen ([see Eric Evans comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-292?focusedCommentId=12866935&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_12866935)).  That being said, I have it running as a Windows service using Apache's procrunner (prunsrv).  I have not noticed any issues running under Windows.